# Sitecore > search index not updating for new site nodes

Tags: indexing, sitecore

I have created a new Sitecore site node and my web site search functionality is not working for the new site node. I have rebuilt the search index via the Indexing Manager, but the indexes have not got updated for the new language. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm a little confused, first you mentioned that you have created new site (I assume you mean adding a new entry into <sites> xml configuration), but then you also mention that it is somewhat related to a new language. Since site and language functionality are two separate functionalities, it would be best if you could elaborate more on your setup and what you are trying to achieve.